# How to run a scheduled task in Websphere 6.1 clustered environment

Tags: java, web-applications, websphere

I would like to run a background task on some interval from a web application I have deployed on Websphere 6.1 clustered environment. The task will access a database, send emails, and write to the database.

I was thinking about kicking off a thread when the web app is first loaded, as suggested here: [Background Thread for a Tomcat servlet app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791986/background-thread-for-a-tomcat-servlet-app).

Since it is a clustered environment, what would be the best way to NOT have task run on each individual node of the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the WAS [Scheduler service](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r1/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/welc6tech_sch.html).

It says of clustered environments:

> **Scheduler daemons in a cluster**
>
> When multiple schedulers are
>   configured to use the same tables (as
>   is the case in a clustered
>   environment), any of the daemons can
>   find a task and set the alarm in its
>   Java virtual machine (JVM). The task
>   is executed in the virtual machine
>   where the scheduler daemon first runs,
>   until the daemon is stopped and
>   another daemon starts. If an
>   application on server1 schedules a
>   task to run and server2 was started
>   before server1, then the task runs on
>   server2.