# Tomcat failed to start when calling Thread.sleep inside servlet on server startup

Tags: java, tomcat

Tomcat failed to start when calling Thread.sleep inside servlet on server startup.

There is a Servet which is loaded at server start up. Inside the init method of servlet, sendMail method of MailSenderUtility class is called. Inside the sendMail method I have called Thread.sleep() method to sleep the program for a calculated time if it is not 8 PM.

Due to this code (Thread.sleep) server does not getting started. If I delete the Thread.sleep statement, it is working fine.

Please help and let me know if there is better way to do it. For your knowledge I can not use Quartz and Java Timer class for my scheduler due to some limitations.

Thank to you all for support.

Dheeraj

Answer (score 2):

Dheeraj you cant "stop" the thread responsible for the initialization. Do it somewhere else since Servlet object is not suitable for this.

What you need is [ContextListener](http://tomcat-configure.blogspot.com/2009/01/tomcat-context-listener-example.html). Well described [also here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/791986/background-thread-for-a-tomcat-servlet-app).

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Obviously you are putting the main thread to sleep.

Instead you should create a separate thread and run MailSenderUtility on it. Then you can sleep this thread without affecting the main initialization thread.

A simple example:

```
    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            // start MailSenderUtility here
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: Well yeah but never forget to properly stop the thread otherwise you run into issues during context redeployments (errors in the tomcat log). I hihgly recommend to use ContextListener and to properly implement its contextDestroyed method.

Comment: Agreed. Your solution is undoubtedly cleaner. Mine is just a quick hack.